# Как добавить Java 8 в Android?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли использовать лямбда-выражения? И вообще - можно ли Java 8 туда добавить?
 Только официально, а не "левыми" путями.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно в Android Studio 3.0. Лямбды доступны в ней для любого minSdkVersion, достаточно добавить в каждый модуль, либо содержащий Java 8 код, либо содержащий зависимости с Java 8 байткодом.

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Все подробности здесь
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: А сам функционал 8 ки?так ккак лямбада эт лишь малая часть

Comment: @elik, по ссылке все расписано, что доступно из Java 8 для любого minSdkVersion, что с 24. Вы же написали что вам нужны лямбды, я ответил.

Comment: Cпасибо благодарю !

Answer (score 4):

Есть описание в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html):

`android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}`

это необходимо добавить в `build.gradle`

Comment: jack объявлен как deprecated. Поддержка лямбд реализована через  Android plugin 3.0. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html Ну и лямбды это лишь малая часть java 8, полной поддержки java 8 нет.

Comment: @temq, с API26 (О) уже вроде как есть.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Делать ничего не надо, она поддерживает Java 8 и лямбды по умолчанию. Но работать будет только на Android 7 и выше.

Comment: Да я тоже нашел этот ответ там написано что полная поддержка java 8 only Android (N) обидно)

Comment: Полная полная только с Oreo. В Nougat пару фич еще не хватает.

Answer (score 1):

К описанным выше способам поддержки лябмда выражений добавлю еще один:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5' //lambda support
}
```